# Find matching text from a text column

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, text-mining

This is my first time to use Data Analytics tool to figure out a solution to a problem.
I have a table with following columns `Person ID, Person Name, Note ID, Note (notes is a free form text where a call representative can enter their comments) Insert User`. I have been given list of `key phrases` to be identified from the `Note` column. These key phrases are in a sentence format.
Example:[image]

I have to find exact or a similar matching phrase from those notes. The format of my final report would look something like this
[image]

I looked into couple of articles related to text matching which suggested options such as

> fuzzywuzzy, Doc2vec, Difflib, python-levenshtein

It is all so confusing. Even if I get a starter to pick the best suitable option, I can may be take it from there. Any suggestions?
Thank you so much!

Comment: can you upload the json text data than image

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are suggesting is a text summarization problem. It can be of two types **abstractive** - understanding the text distribution and then producing a summary, **extractive** - extracting specific words from the text to produce a summary. Clearly, your problem falls in the latter category. Also, since you have the labels to be generated it is a supervised text summarization problem. Take a look at this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220479857_Learning_Algorithms_for_Keyphrase_Extraction) regarding algorithms for the same. It suggests two solutions for a similar problem, you'll of course have to modify them a bit and see which one works best for you. Good luck.